# How to stop User Control execution process until the User responds to the user control

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Hi we have a WPF Application which we have developed using MVVM pattern. We have such kind of architecture where we have some DLLs which contain some POP UPs (WPF Windows) which are no where realeted to our Main Application.
Using some internal layer we are doing some analysis and dynamically picking the required dlls based on some conditions and we are showing those pop ups on main application by joining the thread of that dll with the WPF main application thread.

But now we want to remove those pop ups and instead of pop ups we want to show usercontrols in main window by replacing all these windows with usercontrol.

So now also we faced some issue with thread in dlls , and from dlls again we are sending the usercontrol object to main application and able to load in main application.

But earlier while showing pop ups we used the window.ShowDialog which will stop the further processing in that dll untill user responds.

But as now we changed those windows to usercontrols and we dont have any such mechanism in usercontrol which will stop further processing untill user responds to it, so before user responds the execution in dll is goinng to next level which we dont want.

Can any one help how to get the Window.ShowDialog() equivalent functionality while displaying or loading a User Control as well?

We tried setting up some flags in an infinite loop in usercontrol untill user responds , but we are getting again wpf thread issues even there.

Hi this is the code snippet and details as well:

We have one DLL called some  XYZTest.dll which is of  type user library where we have some wpf window which will be invoked from the same DLL from some other class Package.cs as follows earlier:

### Initial Pop Up Approach where we are showing WPF window from dynamically invoked dll as pop up on the main application :

```
     If(somecount>0)
{
         MessagePanel  messagePanel=new    MessagePanel(request.ClientInfo.IPAddress);
        messagePanel.WindowStartupLocation =        System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
         messagePanel.ShowDialog();
        }

       Return obj;
```

In this above code untill user responds to the above window  the execution process does not go further…

And this XYZTest.dll is dynamically invoked by a business layer and there using the following code we are attaching this thread to main application or thread which is our ui…

### Dynamic Invocation of that DLL and joining thread to main window:::

```
  Thread thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { retrunObject =         invoke(requestObject); });
     thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
     thread.Start();
     thread.Join();
     return retrunObject;
```

But now we don’t want to display pop ups and so I wanted to change all the windows to user controls and wanted to display the respected user control in the main application dynamically.

So now we changed code something like this...

### 1st approach::

```
PangaeaServerApplication.App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        MessagePanelUserControl userControl = new MessagePanelUserControl();

                        MainApplication.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel.ADDClientUUTPopUP( userControl);

                        while (true)
                        {
                            if (isRunning == false)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                userControl.trigger.WaitOne(2000);
                            }
                        }

                    }));
```

### 2nd Approach::

```
 Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
             {
                 // Create our context, and install it:
                 SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                     new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                         Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

               MessagePanelUserControl userControl = new MessagePanelUserControl ();
```

MainApplication.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel.ADDClientUUTPopUP(userControl);

```
         while (true)
         {
             if (isRunning == false)
             {
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 userControl.trigger.WaitOne(2000);
             }
         }

         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
     }));

     newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     // Make the thread a background thread
     newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
     // Start the thread
     newWindowThread.Start();
```

Here my intention is to achieve a behaviour similar to   messagePanel.ShowDialog(); where  the execution will not proceed further ...but while using autoresentevent I am getting complete ui hanged and if I am not using any timers and all then not able to stop execution untill user responds...

Comment: Post some code to understand you issue.

Comment: HI @AyyappanSubramanian Thanks for shoiwng interest in my query please look the modified post for the details.